# Can a batch script be used to pull individual numbers from a list and plug them sequentially into an existing script?

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I've written a batch script that is used to locate and copy files based on user input. The problem is that right now, the user must input each data point individually. The data in question looks (in part) like this:

```
  PLAN & VERSION: S11L-ABC-R Sheets ELEVATION: ‘ABC’    GARAGE: 2 CAR, EXTENDED, 3 CAR, & DROP
1 set of pages 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1C, 6.1C, 7.1, E.1 (FULL SIZE) Framer
1 set of pages 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 6.1C, E.1 (FULLSIZE) Foundation
1 set of pages 2.1, 4.1 (HALF SIZE) Finish
1 set of pages 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, E.1 (HALF SIZE) Plumber
1 set of pages E.1 (FULL SIZE) Elec
1 set of pages 2.1, 6.1C (FULL SIZE) Sider
1 set of pages 1.1 (HALF SIZE) EXC
1 set of pages 2.1, 6.1C (HALF SIZE) Mason
```

The numbers I need are 1.1, 1.2, ...etc. The order is also vital. Aside from left to right, the order of the lines would be 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8. (All the full size followed by all the half size, which is always presented in this sequence.)

There are several variables I've already accounted for in the manual-entry script, which is why I want to be able to pull the first number on this list, automatically run it into the other script, then pull the second, and on and on.

When entered manually, these numbers fill in for %sheet% here:

```
if exist "*-%LR%-%sheet%.pdf" (
echo File found in given path.>>C:\Users\Production\Desktop\Temp\log.txt
for %%f in (*%LR%-%sheet%.pdf) do echo Matching sheet is: %%f>>C:\Users\Production\Desktop\Temp\log.txt 
goto :copy
) else (
goto :checkdash
)
```

And then, for the copying:

```
:loop
if exist "C:\Users\Production\Desktop\Temp\Catch\%Lot%\*%a%_*.*" set /a a+=1 && goto :loop
for %%f in (*%LR%-%sheet%.pdf) do xcopy /i *%LR%-%sheet%.pdf "C:\Users\Production\Desktop\Temp\Catch\%lot%\%a%_%%f*" & echo Success.>>C:\Users\Production\Desktop\Temp\log.txt
cd %input%
goto :Sheet Entry
```

And then a whole bunch of ifs and loops to account for several possible variations in the sheet names.

I've played around with a for /f loop, but even when I manage to get the right value (skipping lines, setting delims, and asking for a specific token) it returns the value on each and every line, then mixes in some text when it gets to parts of the given document with other irrelevant info.

I also played around with 'find' a bit, thinking I could output the results into a .txt file and subsequently read that to assign the proper values to %sheet%. Still couldn't get the results I was looking for. (This did make it easier to re-order the paragraph so that the lines would be sequential for my needs, though.)

These paragraphs of numbers typically come grouped together, so there would be 5 or so of those with similar numbers and structures. They also come in a word doc which I just save as .txt so that the batch script can read it properly.

I don't know if what I'm trying to accomplish is really possible, so if it's not, so be it. And since you're probably wondering why in the world I'm using a batch script for this - well, it seemed like the easiest thing to learn quick (had no idea what any of this meant two weeks ago) and I can't use powershell because I don't have admin privileges.

Sorry if I gave too much irrelevant information, I'm not really sure what's helpful and what isn't. Happy to give more if it helps.

Comment: Mmm... Your description is confusing... Please, post the _output_ you want to generate based on the _input_ you posted already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don't understand what you want...

Anyway, I wrote some code; here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%s in (FULL HALF) do for /F "tokens=4*" %%a in ('findstr "%%s" test.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in (^"!line:^, ^=^
%dont remove%
!^") do echo %%c
)
```

... and this is the output:

```
1.1
1.2
2.1
3.1
4.1
5.1C
6.1C
7.1
E.1 (FULL SIZE) Framer
1.1
1.2
2.1
6.1C
E.1 (FULLSIZE) Foundation
E.1 (FULL SIZE) Elec
2.1
6.1C (FULL SIZE) Sider
2.1
4.1 (HALF SIZE) Finish
1.1
2.1
3.1
4.1
E.1 (HALF SIZE) Plumber
1.1 (HALF SIZE) EXC
2.1
6.1C (HALF SIZE) Mason
```

If we remove the `"delims="` from the second `for /F`, we get this:

```
1.1
1.2
2.1
3.1
4.1
5.1C
6.1C
7.1
E.1
1.1
1.2
2.1
6.1C
E.1
E.1
2.1
6.1C
2.1
4.1
1.1
2.1
3.1
4.1
E.1
1.1
2.1
6.1C
```

So?